# An opposite to the process of forming extensions

Tags: reference-request, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring (with unity) and let $A$ and $B$ be $R$-modules.
An *extension of $A$ by $B$* is a short exact sequence of $R$-modules
$$ 0 \to B \stackrel\mu\to E \stackrel\epsilon\to A \to 0.$$
In English, $B$ is a submodule of $E$ and the quotient $E/B$ is isomorphic to $A$.
In homological algebra we learn about the $\operatorname{Ext}$ (bi)functor, which given $A$ and $B$ returns an Abelian group classifying extensions up to equivalence.

My question is the following: is there a kind of reverse process to this?

> Given a single module $E$, is it possible to classify the ways in which $E$ can be written as an extension $0 \to B \stackrel\mu\to E \stackrel\epsilon\to A \to 0$, up to an appropriate kind of equivalence?

Comment: The problem you mention is just the problem: What are the submodules of $E$ and the corresponding quotient modules?

Comment: I am not sure how one can answer this question, surely there will be rings for which one can do this classification; I think a  more appropriate question is "how?".  Also, to make this problem more "fancy", this question is the same as ("up to an appropriate kind of equivalence") understanding the comultiplication of the Hall algebra of your original algebra.